# Windows Forms ComboBox Items not loading from data source as specified

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So I have created a combobox in windows forms. I then went into the properties and set the data source to a table from a database. I set the display and value members to the column which contains the values i want to generate as the items for the combo box. But when I compile the set of items are empty.

I know there are a lot of similar questions on this site and the internet and I have spent a few hours attempting those solutions but nothing seems to work.

EDIT

Here is the code automatically generated by windows forms. I did not write any code that affects this combobox

```
        // fieldsBindingSource2
        // 
        this.fieldsBindingSource2.DataMember = "Fields";
        this.fieldsBindingSource2.DataSource = this.tMSDataSet;
        // 
        // FieldSelectionComboBox
        // 
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info;
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedItem", this.fieldsBindingSource, "Field Name", true));
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.fieldsBindingSource, "Field Name", true));
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.DataSource = this.fieldsBindingSource2;
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.DisplayMember = "Field Name";
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(83, 3);
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.MaxLength = 50;
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.Name = "FieldSelectionComboBox";
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.TabIndex = 7;
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.ValueMember = "Field Name";
        this.FieldSelectionComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.FieldSelectionComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

EDIT

I do not know if this changes anything, but the combo box is in a User Control, and I dynamically add the User Control to the window pragmatically.

I have since attempted another approach. This way simply reads all the items from the database and adds the records to the combo box items. But This does not work either. Below is my code for this attempt.

```
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
        SqlDataReader Reader = query.ExecuteReader();
        AutoCompleteStringCollection List = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                List.Add(Reader.GetString(0));
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException)
            {
                int t_listItem = Reader.GetInt32(0);
                List.Add(t_listItem.ToString());
            }
        }

        NewTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        NewTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = List;
```

I then get an error on some of the fields being read. the error is, SQLException was unhandled, invalid object name.

I have tried narrowing down what part is invalid whether it is type or length etc. But I have found nothing. All values in the database are varchar(50) and are all accepted and entered properly to the table. Example of words that throw a exception are "Initiation" and "Trainer" but things like "[First Name]" work.

Any help on either approach would be great.

Comment: Are you sure you have SELECT permission on the table? If you bungle one of the fieldnames you won't get a warning - they just don't work.

Comment: I am positive i have no restrictions on the database

Comment: When you set a breakpoint, what is the value of `this.tMSDataSet`?

Comment: it contains various information on the tables and other stuff from the database. ex tables and their columns

Comment: Is the data in `this.FieldSelectionComboBox.DataSource = this.fieldsBindingSource2;` the same as it is in `this.tMSDataSet`?

Comment: There might be some `resetting your combobox's DataSource` so that it did not actually have any DataSource. You should perform some debugging to find out where it is. You should also check if after loading, your `combobox's DataSource` really has something in it, though at some time before, it had some data loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Please set below properties

```
this.FieldSelectionComboBox.ValueMember = "Column1"; // Will be the column name present in your database table
this.FieldSelectionComboBox.DisplayMember = "Column2"; // Will be the column name present in your database table
```

Thanks

Manoj

Comment: if you look in the code I provided above, I have already added those exact lines of code.

Comment: If your field names contain spaces try using [Field Name]. Or edit the SQL to use a field name w/o spaces. In general avoid using spaces in field names.

Comment: I honestly thought this might do it but it changed nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. it came from code in another area that was conflicting.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some VB.Net code that might help others. It is general library code that returns a DataView. Use the DataView as the DataSource. No need to add items in code.

FieldSelectionComboBox.DataSource = GetDataView(SQL)

```
Function GetDataTable(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal ConnectString As String = "", Optional ByVal SingleRow As Boolean = False) As DataTable ' returns read only Datatable
    Try
        If ConnectString.Length = 0 Then ConnectString = g.OISConnectString()
        Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectString)
            Dim rdr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, con)
            If SingleRow Then
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow Or CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Else
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            End If
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(rdr)
            rdr.Close()
            Return dt
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "GetDataTable")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
Function GetDataView(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal ConnectString As String = "") As DataView ' returns read only Dataview
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = GetDataTable(SQL, ConnectString)
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
            Return dv
        End If
    Catch ex2 As NullReferenceException
        Return Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "GetDataView")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```